# SwiperJS, Blade Laravel: How to dynamically create a new swiper from inside a @foreach loop inside a BLADE template?

Tags: laravel-blade, swiper.js

I have a @foreach loop, where each item inside the loop is a "row" representing a carousel (SwiperJS ) instance. If there are 1, 2, or 3, I can just manually initialize the swiper instance in the JS section with

JS

```
var swiper1 = new Swiper(".swiperA", { ...}
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".swiperB", { ...}
var swiper3 = new Swiper(".swiperC", { ...}
...
var swiper26 = new Swiper(".swiperZ", { ...}
```

HTML BLADE

```
@foreach($rowItem as $rI => $row) {{ROW x-dim}}
    <div class="swiper swiperA menu-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            @foreach($var as $key=>$variables) {{imgs in each ROW y-dim}}
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <image src="$var->img_link" alt="image">
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

How do I dynamically generate a carousel (SwiperJS) instance for each row?

not using VUE, or REACT.

There might be 1 row (1 swiperJS instance), or there might be 10 rows (SwiperJS instances).

[LAYOUT OF PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4pdX.png)

based on the number of items in $row from @foreach loop

Thanks,
Cindi